# availability of big files on multiple server

Tags: file, handle

first thing: Sorry for my bad english ;)

I have to handle many (1.000 - 30.000) big files with a size from 200mb up to 2gb. The demand of this files is diffrent (0 - 300 downloads/file).
This is why single files must saved on 2 or more servers.

My servers placed in different datacenters (france), with different HDDs (750gb to 4tb).

I need a solution to handle/blancing this files on 7+ Servers.

Actually i share this files with PHP and ncftpget/ncftpput, but its very slow :/

Comment: I'm not sure but http://serverfault.com/ or http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ might be more suited for this question.

Comment: Why don't you try [Rsync](http://www.unixtutorial.org/2008/09/how-to-synchronize-directories-with-rsync/)? It's very suitable for file sync usually used in open-source mirrors and your problem is very similar.

Comment: I dont want do Sync all Server, because 10.000 files with a size of 1gb are do big für a 750gb HDD ;)